# UINavigationController from scratch?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view based app that works well. (In other words, I'm not going to start over with a Navigation-Based App template.)

It's an immersive app of sorts and I'm trying to add a Table View that loads in a new view when a button is pressed.

The loading the nib part works, but I can't seem to be able to add a navigation controller to the new view. I want to see a navigation bar on top with a done button and an edit button. Also, I want to the Table View entries to be empty.

- I added a new file like so:
  `File-> New File -> UINavigationController subclass`. I checked the UITableViewController Subclass and `With XIB for user interface.`

All I see when the view is pulled up is a blank Table View. I am able to customize things in the view controller.

What can I do to make the table show a navigation bar and be editable? I need some direction here please.

EDIT: I'm working with the latest Public SDK. (XCode 3.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navigation bar usually comes with a navigation controller, not with the table view controller.

You can add the navigation bar manually, but that will require altering the table view, to change it to just a regular view with a table view inside of it, and changing your table view controller to be a regular view controller that manually handles the table view stuff.

The simpler alternative is to wrap your table view controller inside of a navigation controller before you display it.  Something like:

```
MyTableViewController *myViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
[myViewController release];

//Now display navigationController instead of myViewController, using something like:
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is `initWithRootViewController` a convenience method that will automatically release itself when finished?

Comment: It just creates a navigation controller object that contains a view controller (in this case the table view controller). However, since it's an init method, you'll need to release it yourself later.