# storyboard uinavigationcontroller does not allow me to drag items in

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an existing ios5/xcode 4.2 app, and I want a button to open a view that will display a list of items, and have a back button and an add new button.

I thought I could achieve this by adding a button to the main view controller, then dragging in to the storyboard a new UITableViewController, then embed a UINavigationController (editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller).

Then i right clicked on the button, dragged it to the navigation controller, and thought, ok this should work.

However, there is no back button, and xcode will not let me drag one in, nor will it allow me to drag in the button bar item "[+]" for the link to add new.

When I run the app, the list shows, of course I have no way to go back to the view controller with the button on it.

What am i doing wrong? - thanks.
(my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886269/uinavigationcontroller-from-scratch) 
but for xcode 4.2)

Comment: Is the table view the root view of the navigation controller, or is the view with the button in also part of the navigation controller?

Comment: I noticed that I have a new warning - (null) is not a valid controller containment key path - googling

Comment: @jrturton - yes the table view is the root view of the navigation controller.  view with the button, judging by that warning, needs to be a controller container, i guess like a tab controller, but I do not have a tab in there.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to drag `UIBarButtonItem`s directly into the `UINavigationController`. I don't think IB lets you do this--you have to put them in the simulated navigation bar of each child view controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Embed the main view controller, not the new one, in a `UINavigationController`. This should add a simulated `UINavigationBar` to the main view (if not, set one up under Simulated Metrics). At this point you should be able to drop in a `UIBarButtonItem` to the main view's simulated bar.

Next, draw a connection from your button to the new `UITableViewController` to set up a push segue. At runtime, the back button will appear in the bar automatically.

Comment: OK, I am going to guess that the parent of a navigation controller has to be a navigation controller for this to work, and since the viewcontroller the button is on, is not, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you try and drag the items into your view controller that the storyboard is zoomed in. XCode won't let you add items if you are zoomed out.